# My text for output file is not the same as input

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  int c;

  FILE *poem = fopen("short.txt", "r");
  FILE *html = fopen("index.html", "w");

  if (poem == NULL){
      perror("Error in opening file");
      return(-1);   
  }
  if (html == NULL){
      perror("Error in opening file");
      return(-1);   
  }

  while((c = fgetc(poem)) != EOF) {
       c = getc(poem);
       fputc(c, html);
  }

  fclose (poem);
  fclose (html);
  return 0;
}
```

I've been searching and trying but I can't figure it out. My read file has less than a sentence of words, and then when it outputs it to `index.html` it's all jumbled up. I don't really understand know whats wrong with the code. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: jumbled up, or every second character?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing 2 reads for each write

```
  while((c = fgetc(poem)) != EOF) {  // read
       c = getc(poem);               // read
       fputc(c, html);               // write
  }
```

Comment: No your comment fixed it. "That" as in your answer.

Comment: I mean I didn't write code without the problem or tell you what to add or delete from your code. You did that on your own :)